# In Espresso How Do I click on external Deep link and Validate it?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm looking for below scenario if that can be automated?
Scenario:I Click on a link in my gmail account and my android app is launched
Question: how do i launch the gmail app , search for relevant email with relevant text and click on the link in order to launch my testing app in QA?

Comment: Probably this answer in this question can help in getting your way for the specific scenario you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074173/automating-deep-linking-using-android-espresso/47813474#47813474. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I put a lot of work into this recently, so please update and ask questions.

Short answer: use uiautomator+uiautomatorviewer.

I used sms, which added some complexity but saved a lot of time b/c you really don't want to setup gmail.

quicksearchbox is also good (faster) but only on some APIs.

Comment: Can you share your solution for launching app using deeplinks and verifying   views?

Comment: It was for a company I'm not working for anymore :( But see; https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html ..     http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html  etc

Comment: Yes, please check my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951216/how-to-write-tests-for-deep-links-in-android