# How to write tests for deep links in Android?

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-testing, android-espresso

I would like to write tests for [Android app with deep link cases](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) using UI testing framework (Espresso) - launch app using only ACTION_VIEW intent and check all views on opened screen.

But looks like Espresso (even espresso-intents) doesn't have this functionality, and require to define Activity class.

I tried this way, but it doesn't work properly, because launched app twice - standard launch using AppLauncherActivity (required by Espresso) and launch via deep link.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DeeplinkAppLauncherTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<AppLauncherActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(AppLauncherActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testDeeplinkAfterScollDownAndBackUp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("myapp://search/777"));
        activityRule.launchActivity(intent);

        onView(withId(R.id.search_panel)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

}
```

I would like to launch testing app using only deep link without standard launch.
Do you know, how to do it?

Comment: I already replied to same kind of question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074173/automating-deep-linking-using-android-espresso/47813474#47813474. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found one option - just added deep link opening parameters for existed intent and use standard activity launch:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<AppLauncherActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<AppLauncherActivity>(AppLauncherActivity.class){
    @Override protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
        Intent intent = super.getActivityIntent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://search/777"));
        return intent;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer is helpful, but nowadays the `ActivityTestRule` class has been [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule).

We can use `ActivityScenario` instead.

Here is a **Kotlin** example:

```
class MyDeepLinkTest {

    private lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<LoadingActivity>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Intents.init()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Intents.release()
        scenario.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun myTest() {
        val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), LoadingActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra("example_extra1", "Value 1")
            .putExtra("example_extra2", 777)

        scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(intent)

        // Test code goes here (e.g. intent causes to start MainActivity)
        intended(hasComponent(MainActivity::class.java.name))
    }

}
```

I also found this [blog post](https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/better-tests-with-androidxs-activityscenario-in-kotlin-part-1-6a6376b713ea) with additional examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<AppLauncherActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(AppLauncherActivity.class, false, false);
```

There are multiple constructors for creating an ActivityTestRule. The third one is `launchActivity`. Set it to false as shown above because you manually start that activity afterwards with `activityRule.launchActivity(intent)`. This should prevent it from starting twice