# Automating deep linking using android espresso

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-espresso

I want to write espresso scripts to test deep linking and have no idea how to begin with. Looking for solutions that'll help me get more idea, possibly step by step procedure on how to get started.

For ex : I am looking for a scenario like you get a link in gmail tapping on which user should be directed towards the mobile app. How do I get started to test something like this using espresso ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write tests for deep links in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951216/how-to-write-tests-for-deep-links-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with an activity rule

```
 @Rule
 public ActivityTestRule<YourAppMainActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(YourAppMainActivity.class, true, false);
```

Then you want something to parse the uri from the link and return the intent

```
String uri = "http://your_deep_link_from_gmail"; 
private Intent getDeepLinkIntent(String uri){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(uri))
                .setPackage(getTargetContext().getPackageName());


        return intent;
    }
```

Then you want the activity rule to launch the intent

```
Intent intent = getDeepLinkIntent(deepLinkUri);
mActivityRule.launchActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i believe this will always launch your activity, even if the deeplink you're providing is wrong because testrule.launchActivity will add your component to the intent if the component of the intent is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Well `IntentTestRule` doesn't work properly. So I will try like this with an `ActivityTestRule` :

```
public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class, false, false);
```

And then I will write the proper UI Unit Test to be something like this:

```
@Test
public void testDeeplinkingFilledValue(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
                .getTargetContext(), MyActivity.class );

        Uri data = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("clientName", "Client123").build();
        intent.setData(data);

        Intents.init();
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);


        intended(allOf(
                hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), MyActivity.class)),
                hasExtras(allOf(
                        hasEntry(equalTo("clientName"), equalTo("Client123"))
                ))));
        Intents.release();
}
```

With this you are going to test that the deeplink with a given query parameter is actually being retrieved correctly by your activity that is handling the Intent for the deeplinking.

Comment: Whast is allOf can you include the imports too?  Problem with alot of examples when you don't know where functions come from.

Comment: @JPM has been really a while since I used this code. Perhaps about "intended" and "allOf" can you try if those two imports works for you today?

`import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended` and this other import `import static org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.allOf`