# How to test DeepLinks with espresso

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I want to add tests for all my deep links, to launch them and see if the needed activity is launched and assert over what is showed on that activity.

How can I do it?

## Edit

I ended up testing just the deep linking matching like https://medium.com/@singwai/testing-deep-linking-with-espresso-and-burst-5e1bdb3c5e29 says.

In kotlin:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun test_deepLink_isResolvedBy(url: String, canonicalActivityName: String) {
    val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
    val resolvedActivities =
        appContext.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)

    val resolverActivityMissing = resolvedActivities.none {
      it.activityInfo.packageName == appContext.packageName &&
          it.activityInfo.name == canonicalActivityName
    }

    if (resolverActivityMissing) {
      fail("$url is not resolved for $canonicalActivityName")
    }
}
```

Then I check if there are activities that resolve my urls, and test each activity on its own test.

Comment: I already replied to same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074173/automating-deep-linking-using-android-espresso/47813474#47813474 hope it helps!

Comment: @Caipivara did you get this working?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly nope

Comment: I take it then that you tried the `launchActivityWithIntent` code below....I'm using same code to do what you're trying so curious what issue you're still seeing when using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to use something like following:

```
launchActivityWithIntent(getActivity().getPackageName(),
        YourActivityThatHandlesDeepLink.class,
        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(link)));
```

Comment: Who is the owner of this function `launchActivityWithIntent`  ?

Comment: @Caipivara https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html

Comment: It works, thanks. I ended up using an `ActivityTestRule` and `rule.launchActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(deepLink))) `instead of that.

Comment: As `ActivityTestRule` is deprecated, this Kotlin example may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929217/3692788